# JAVA - Concurrency - multi-producer/multi-consumer request and response queue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have 3 types of threads. Main thread, worker, client.
I also have 2 queues, a request and a response queue.

The main thread spawns many clients. Each client will request something and that should be added to the main's request queue. The main will spawn the appropriate worker and the worker will process the request. When it is done it adds [result, calling thread #] to the response queue. each client will wait after a request, for the response. how should i go about this?

im thinking i should use concurent linked queue for the queues. is this okay?
should the client peek until it finds its thread id and the poll? is it hypotehtically possible for the head to change between peek and poll? i dont want to add in locks as there will be alot of contention and delays.

this has to be thread safe and concurrent and not have any deadlock or starvation.

Comment: You probably want to put up an [mcve]. It is always hard to answer questions that merely explain what your code is doing, on a broad, unspecific level. Beyond that: you are asking more than one question here. Please step back and make your question more specific; and if there are several different things to ask about - ask several different questions!

Answer (score 0):

I would have a single request queue, and then a separate response queue for each client.  As part of the request sent to the worker, I would put a reference to the client's response queue so the clients don't have to continuously `peak()` through a single response queue.

Use `BlockingQueues` for both the request and response queues.  Put a higher capacity on the request queue (i.e. Greater than the number of client threads) to eliminate starvation.  The capacity for the response queues can be just one.  Use `put()` and `take()` instead of `peak()` and `poll()`.

Here's the sequence:

1. Client creates a request.
2. Client puts it on the request queue and blocks if the queue is full.  (This is why you make the capacity on the request queue higher.)
3. Client calls `take()` on it's own response queue and blocks, because it is empty.
4. Worker thread spawns, or was already spawned and blocked on the empty request queue.
5. Worker thread removes the item from the request queue and processes it.  Once complete, it puts it on the client's response queue (using the reference to the response queue passed in the request.)
6. This causes the client to unblock.  The client removes the response from its response queue and processes it.

Comment: Answering a question by text where most sentences end with a "?" isnt maybe the correct approach In other words: you are mostly asking for clarifications. That doesn't make up a valid answer!

Comment: Sorry, I know.  I would put it in a comment, but I don't have 50 points yet.

Comment: I put up a comment to the OP. And: the system that you need 50 points to comment is on purpose. As it is on purpose that you shouldnt use answers to bypass this restriction. Please delete your answer ... otherwise it will just create more churn.

Comment: How about I just update my answer once I get clarification.  I've literally implemented exactly what the guy is asking probably 20 times.

Comment: I wouldnt hold my breath on that. And: if you wait for changes, then mark this question as a "favorite". You see, other people will be looking at your answer. There might be downvotes coming in, and more importantly: your answer shows up in review queues. It means that other people start **wasting** time reviewing it. If you want to wait for the question to improve ... fine - but dont keep a **bad** answer around while waiting.

Comment: a worker thread is spawned for every item in the request queue. I don't see the point either to do it this way. this is my assignment unfortunately

Comment: Okay, well you can still pass a reference to the client's response queue in the request queue.  I don't recommend using a single response queue, otherwise you'll have to have each client continuously poll the items in the queue which is pretty messy.  Much easier if each client is waiting for only its own responses.

Comment: Tom, take another look at my answer.  Had some pretty glaring typos in there the first time.  Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Okay thanks!! From my prompt it seems I have to use one response queue, but using multiple would really simplify it. If I have to just use the one queue it seems like my only option is to sleep till the worker does a notify? If that's true should I just poll right away or peek then poll?

Comment: If you have to have a single response queue, you could probably have a dispatcher thread listening on that queue and routing the responses to the appropriate client threads.  Of course, then you have to find a way to make the clients block waiting for a request to be dispatched to them.  There you could probably just use wait()/notify()...or perhaps you could pass the messages from the main response queue to a client specific blocking queue that it's blocked on.

Comment: And by "listening" I mean the dispatcher thread would simply call take() on the response queue and wait for a response to appear.